# Why does RegisterHotKey return false? user32.dll

Tags: c#, user32, registerhotkey

when i run `RegisterHotKey`, it returns false. what are possible reasons?

```
internal void RegisterHotKey2(ModifierKeys modifier, Keys key)
{
    _cID += 1;
    if (!RegisterHotKey(_window.Handle, _cID, (uint)modifier, (uint)key))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("oh no: " + modifier.ToString() + " + " + key.ToString());
        throw new InvalidOperationException("couldn't register noooooo");
    }
}
```

**OLD VERSION (don't judge please)**

```
internal void RegisterHotKey2(ModifierKeys modifier, Keys key)
{
    _cID += 1;
    if (!RegisterHotKey(_window.Handle, _cID, (uint)modifier, (uint)key))
        Console.WriteLine("oh no: " + modifier.ToString() + " + " + key.ToString());
    throw new InvalidOperationException("couldn't register noooooo");
}
```

Comment: Have you checked MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx ?

Comment: As the code stands it always throws the exception.

Comment: @failed.down How do you know it's returning `false`? Because the exception is thrown? As 500 pointed out, the code is going to throw the exception no matter what `RegisterHotKey` returns...

Comment: wait i corrected it and it's still returning false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that your code will always throw exception, try change to below..

```
    internal void RegisterHotKey2(ModifierKeys modifier, Keys key)
        {
            _cID += 1;
            if (!RegisterHotKey(_window.Handle, _cID, (uint)modifier, (uint)key))
             {
                Console.WriteLine("oh no: " + modifier.ToString() + " + " + key.ToString()); 
                throw new InvalidOperationException("couldn't register noooooo");
             }
        }
```